# Apache serves .svg file without Content-type header

Tags: apache, apache2, configuration, svg, content-type

Apache is serving an `.svg` file, but the HTTP response does not have a `Content-type` header.  Consequently, Chrome is displaying the text of the `.svg` file, rather than the desired image.

My goal is for Apache to serve the `.svg` file with the header `Content-type: image/svg+xml` so that Chrome will display the image.

Aside: The `.svg` file originally came from here:
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/106114/bee.svg

My Apache configuration file is intentionally as small as possible.  It is:

```
DocumentRoot            /path/to/docroot
ErrorLog                /tmp/apache.log
PidFile                 /tmp/apache.pid
Listen                  0.0.0.0:8000
ServerName              127.0.0.1

LoadModule  mpm_prefork_module  /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
LoadModule  authz_core_module   /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_core.so

LoadModule  mime_module         /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so
TypesConfig             /etc/mime.types
AddType                 image/svg+xml  .svg
```

I am running Apache as provided by Ubuntu 20.04 (version `2.4.41-4ubuntu3`).

My question is, what configuration changes will cause Apache to provide the desired `Content-type` header for the `.svg` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have, I think, tracked down the problem.

Initially, Chrome cached the `.svg` content without a `Content-type`.

I then changed Apache's configuration to set `Content-type: image/svg+xml`.

I then reloaded the image in Chrome.  Chrome sends a `GET` request, but with some cache related headers (for example, one such header is `If-Modified-Since`).

Apache responds with a `304 Not Modified` status.  According to Chrome Developer Tools, this response does not include a `Content-type` header.  If the Developer Tools is correct, then Chrome would be unaware that the `Content-type` has changed.

If I `touch` the `.svg` file, or if I clear Chrome's cache, then the image will reload and will be displayed as an image.